# Reinstalled Windows 10 on Asus x205t laptop—touchpad, keyboard, and audio don't work and aren't recognized

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I had major issues with this Asus X205T laptop several months ago after a Windows 10 update. It wouldn't boot up properly anymore. So, I thought it was a good time to wipe the drive and install a Linux distro. Unfortunately, Linux doesn't play well with this computer. So, I just re-installed Windows 10 (32 bit).

In order to complete the install I had to plug in an external usb keyboard and a mouse.

So, the usb ports, wifi, and webcam *are* working (as are most things, as far as I can tell).

However, the built-in touchpad, keyboard, and speakers do *not* work.

I *can* use a keyboard and mouse if I plug them into the usb ports. I *cannot* use the audio, even if I plug in headphones.

These items don't even show up in any way, anywhere that I can (checked in settings, as well as device manager).

I have run all the updates.

I tried [downloading drivers from Asus](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/HelpDesk_Download/)  but ran into problems.

The "Audio Realtek" driver ran through the installation process that was included in the download, but after restarting the computer, nothing had changed.

The "SmartGesture" driver (which I assume is for the touchpad) wouldn't do anything at all.

How can I get the touchpad, keyboard, and audio working?

edit: I've searched for the specific parts, but they're just the stock, built-in parts that seem to be manufactured specifically for this laptop.  For example, [this is the only thing close to a part reference I could find for the keyboard/touchpad](http://notebookparts.com/asus-eeebook-x205ta-11-6-palmrest-keyboard-and-touchpad-13nb0732ap0321-rf-39xk2tcjn20/).

Comment: What type of touchpad do you have specifically?  Please provide this information as an edit to your question instead of a comment

Answer (score 0):

I Run Into the same problem. I notice that is post is 4 months old and you most likely have found the solution as I did. Go to https://www.asus.com/US/supportonly/X205TA/HelpDesk_download/ and download the chipset driver. That's it. I now have keyboard, touchpad, sound and webcam.

I hope this help others
Have a great day.